# fscanf() rounds floating point in C

Tags: c, double, scanf, rounding, precision

I have a file with numbers like this:

```
0.000000000000000 1
1.274472000000000 0
1.274472708333333 1
1.274472750000000 0
1.274472791666667 1
1.274472833333333 0
1.274472875000000 1
```

I'm going to do some calculations on those numbers so I read them with fscanf(). The problem is that first number is read with very small precision. I wrote code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  FILE* tf;
  double t;
  int st;


  tf = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if(tf == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
  {
    fscanf(tf, "%lf %d", &t, &st);
    printf("%lf %d\n", t, st);
  }
  fclose(tf);
  return 0;
}
```

The values read during execution are:

```
0.000000 1
1.274472 0
1.274473 1
1.274473 0
1.274473 1
1.274473 0
1.274473 1
```

This is obviously unacceptable... Any idea?

Comment: You can try `%.15lf` in the `printf`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if your file contains less than 100 lines, you'll run into trouble.

Comment: So ... `while(fscanf(tf, "%lf %d", &t, &st) == 2) { printf("%.15lf %d\n", t, st); }`

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]`  without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the command line parameter

Comment: when a system function returns an error indication, call `perror()` to output to `stderr` both the enclosed text and the text reason the system thinks the function failed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After the suggestions made by @Weather Vane & @Michael Walz, I think your code should become like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  FILE* tf;
  double t;
  int st;

  tf = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if(tf == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  /*The ==2  condition will allow reading of the 2 values 
  and at the same time can take care of exceptions if they occur.
  Thus, it smoothly reads the file to it's end, 
  without any need for EOF match OR for looping to match the file size.*/ 
  while(fscanf(tf, "%lf %d", &t, &st)==2)
  {
    //This line will allow the stored number to be presented in a precise form
    printf("%.15lf %d\n", t, st);
  }

  fclose(tf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that I've basically put the suggestions in the comments to the code, with a little explanation. But apart from that, may I know the reason for the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

the statement:

```
fscanf(tf, "%lf %d", &t, &st);
```

actually reads in the full number.

However, to have the call to `printf()` output the full number (rather than the default 'precision') the format specifier `%lf` needs to have the desired 'precision' listed.  I.E.

```
printf( "%.16lf %d\n", t, st );
```

Please read the MAN page for [printf(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)
 for the details